How to make Column's height to be fit with height of parent Row whose height is responsive
I have Row and has Two components in there.
The first component is Column, and the second component is ListView.
the first component Column has 3 Containers.
I want to ListView's height will be set as first Column's height which will be set from children Containers height.
Container(
            color: Colors.amber,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          child: const Text("a\nb"),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          child: const Text("a\nb"),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          child: const Text("a\nb"),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Gaps.h20,
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 10,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return const Text("test");
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )


If I use IntrinsicHeight , then ListView.builder throws infinity height error.
Please help me.

@pskink It throws error with ListView.builder..

Try to give mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween to column

how did you find the following answer?

Try This solution to find out the height of the column.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends State<HomePage> {
  double? widgetHeight = 100;
  GlobalKey textColumnKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (mounted) calculateHeight();
    });
  }

  void calculateHeight() {
    if (textColumnKey.currentContext != null) {
      RenderBox renderBox =
          textColumnKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
      setState(() => widgetHeight = renderBox.size.height);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.amber,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                key: textColumnKey,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    child: const Text("a\nb"),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    child: const Text("a\nb"),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    child: const Text("a\nb"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: widgetHeight,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return const Text("test");
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Avoid Intrinsic Height as much as possible. the docs says:

This class is relatively expensive, because it adds a speculative layout pass before the final layout phase. Avoid using it where possible. In the worst case, this widget can result in a layout that is O(N²) in the depth of the tree.

here is the result:

